# Hadoop Task progress

Tags: hadoop

I need to calculate the progress of each map task running on all nodes in a Hadoop cluster. I was thinking of dividing the size of the processed data by the size of the whole input data, but I am not sure how to get this information for a task.

I see that `TaskStatus` class has a method `getProgress()`, but there is no description for it. Does it provide the value that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a map task, yes `getProgress()` returns how far the mapper has progressed through the input file.  For reduce tasks, the calculation is less straightforward.  [This article](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/) has a pretty good explanation.