# How do you get task level progress from a Hadoop MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to monitor the progress of tasks within a job in Hadoop 1.2.1 MapReduce. I am able to start up my job with the following command:

```
RunningJob runningJob = JobClient.submitJob(conf);
```

I see that I can get the job status of all of the map and reduce tasks like this:

```
  JobStatus jobStatus = runningJob.getJobStatus();

  float mapProgress = jobStatus.mapProgress();
  float reduceProgress = jobStatus.reduceProgress();
```

But I want to be able to get the progress of each task running within the job. Is there an API call to do this?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720050/hadoop-task-progress ?

Comment: I had not, but I had just been reading about the TaskTracker class, but I don't see how you retrieve an instance of it...